# В v-list-item-group не работает v-model когда есть анимация

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Изначально имеется вот такой код

```html
<v-list-item-group v-model="model">
    <v-list-item v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i">
      <v-list-item-icon>
        <v-icon>icon</v-icon>
      </v-list-item-icon>
      <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title>some title</v-list-item-title>
        <v-list-item-subtitle>some subtitle</v-list-item-subtitle>
      </v-list-item-content>
    </v-list-item>
  </v-list-item-group>
```

Пытаюсь к нему прикрутить анимацию через v-slide-y-transition

вот так

```
<v-list-item-group v-model="model">
    <v-slide-y-transition group tag="v-list-item-group" >
      <v-list-item v-for="(item) in items" :key="item.uniqId">
        <v-list-item-icon>
          <v-icon>icon</v-icon>
        </v-list-item-icon>
        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title>some title</v-list-item-title>
          <v-list-item-subtitle>some subtitle</v-list-item-subtitle>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>
    </v-slide-y-transition>
  </v-list-item-group>
```

или вот так

```html
<v-slide-y-transition group tag="v-list-item-group" v-model="model">
      <v-list-item v-for="(item) in items" :key="item.uniqId">
        <v-list-item-icon>
          <v-icon>icon</v-icon>
        </v-list-item-icon>
        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title>some title</v-list-item-title>
          <v-list-item-subtitle>some subtitle</v-list-item-subtitle>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>
    </v-slide-y-transition>
```

В итоге у меня не получается забиндить v-model к v-list-item-group, что бы получать и изменять выделенные итем

Comment: сама анимация работает ?

Comment: Да, работает как и надо

Comment: Думаю загвоздка в том, что компонент `v-list-item-group` не понимает, что вы связываете с `model`. Вот тут в доке написано, как нужно использовать v-model на компонентах - https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components.
Я бы посмотрел подробнее, но неудобно без воспроизводимого примера.

Comment: Ну походу я сам и тупанул немного, когда начал переделывать код под анимацию (что бы ключи были уникальые), потому что мне надо добавлять в начало массива, а если использовать ключ как индекс из массива, то там анимация была на последнем файле, хех

Comment: в общем вроде теперь все работает. Даже запилил пример https://codepen.io/jumpattacker/pen/rNNmMRW?&editable=true&editors=101